# How can I upload a file to a GitHub Codespaces environment?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use [GitHub Codespaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/codespaces), but I don't know how to upload a single file to GitHub Codespaces without the assistance of, for example, github.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple Drag and Drop has worked for me.

To update the answer, there is now also an update option if you right click in the explorer view:
[image]

Comment: There looks to be no Upload option for uploading a file into the top-level directory of the project. The Upload option is there only for subdirectories. Even so, yes, drag-and-drop works.

Comment: For me, unknowingly, only the drag-and-drop feature worked. The "Upload" option in the explorer doesn't work in the web-based editor.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading **files** from your local computer to github codespaces, you can simply right click anywhere in the explorer tab and there you will see an upload option.

[image]

But this upload option does not allow you to upload **folders**, atleast for me it wasn't allowing so for uploading folders, i tried drag and drop into the explorer tab and it worked for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

I was able to transfer a ton of training data from firebase to a codespace using firebase-admin.

in the codespace terminal:

```
pip install firebase-admin 
pip install --ignore-installed <other firebase-admin dependencies>
run whatever script you use to download things from firebase
```

note that there are storage limits